Unable to run two spring boot applications that connect to MySQL on Ubuntu using HikariPool at the same time
I have deployed first spring boot application (.jar rest service) that connects to mysql using HikariPool on ubuntu 22+ (digital ocean), everything works perfectly. However, when i tried to deploy the second spring boot application (.jar also rest service) everything stops working. I start to get Failed to obtain JDBC connection on both console outputs and the first service stops responding.
Any idea on what could be wrong, why the second spring boot stopping the existing service and also freezing the ubuntu server? Please note that this is my first experiencing working with spring boot deployment. kindly help!
Spring boot 1 application.properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LAM_DB
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.idle-timeout=180000
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.validation-timeout=5000
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=HikariPool-LamService-MySQL

spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

Spring boot 1 Datasource
public static HikariDataSource hikariDataSource(String driverClassName, String dbURL,
                                              String dbUsername, String dbPassword) {
        final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setJdbcUrl(dbURL);
        ds.setUsername(dbUsername);
        ds.setPassword(dbPassword);
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts" , "true");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize" , "250");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit" , "2048");
        return ds;
    }

Spring boot 2 application.properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DelushDB
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.idle-timeout=180000
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.mysql.validation-timeout=5000
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=HikariPool-DelushService-MySQL

Spring boot 2 Datasource
public static HikariDataSource hikariDataSource(String driverClassName, String dbURL, String dbUsername, String dbPassword) { final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(); ds.setMaximumPoolSize(100); ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName); ds.setJdbcUrl(dbURL); ds.setUsername(dbUsername); ds.setPassword(dbPassword); ds.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts" , "true"); ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize" , "250"); ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit" , "2048"); return ds; }
